# Question on Dirac delta and Gauss's law

Tags: electrostatics, differential-geometry, gauss-law, vector-fields, regularization

Suppose you have something that looks like an inverse square law, i.e. $\textbf{v} = \frac{1}{r^2}\textbf{1}_r$. We know that it's divergence is 0 except in the origin. We also know that for any smooth surface surrounding the origin, the volume through this surface flows at a rate of $4\pi$. Now my question is, what happens when the origin lies on the surface?

My guess is that it's either $0$ or also $4\pi$.

Comment: Related question: what is $\oint_\gamma dz/z$ when $\gamma$ is a closed path through $0$ in $\Bbb C$?

Comment: The vector field blows up at the surface so you cannot define its flux through it!

Comment: That's what I thought! In our course notes it was formulated as a an extra question to think about at home, but it's stressed that it has an analogous answer as when the origin is surrounded.

Comment: Also, the question apparently comes from Paterson, 1983, book on fluid dynamics

Comment: I can easily imagine someone arguing "reflect the surface in the tangent plane, then deform the new one if necessary so they meet at more than just $0$; their union scores $4\pi$, so they each score $2\pi$". But that's just a regularization convention, analogous to trying the Cauchy PV with the related question I mentioned. This is _also_ related to $\int_0^\infty\delta(x)f(x)dx$ being undefined.

Comment: @J.G. so, it is undefined?